# тепловое отображение точек

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Допустим есть точки у которых в параметрах имеется количество людей. И нужно отображать температуру точки в виде цвета в зависимости от значения количества: мало людей-холодно, много - горячо. Можно ли это реализовать стандартными методами API? Я так понял, что модуль тепловых карт отображает температуру в зависимости от концентрации точек. Мне же нужна температура каждой точки в отдельности в зависимости от ее параметров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, конечно:

```
ymaps.ready(['Heatmap']).then(function init() {

var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [37.782551, -122.445368],
    zoom: 17,
    controls: []
});

var data = {
          type: 'FeatureCollection',
          features: [{
              id: 'id1',
              type: 'Feature',
              geometry: {
                  type: 'Point',
                  coordinates: [37.782551, -122.445368]
              },
              properties: {
                  weight: 1
              }
          }, {
              id: 'id2',
              type: 'Feature',
              geometry: {
                  type: 'Point',
                  coordinates: [37.782745, -122.444586]
              },
              properties: {
                  weight: 10
              }
          },{
              id: 'id3',
              type: 'Feature',
              geometry: {
                  type: 'Point',
                  coordinates: [37.782951, -122.445368]
              },
              properties: {
                  weight: 100
              }
          }]
      };
var heatmap = new ymaps.Heatmap(data, {
    // Радиус влияния.
    radius: 15,
    // Нужно ли уменьшать пиксельный размер точек при уменьшении зума. False - не нужно.
    dissipating: false,
    // Прозрачность тепловой карты.
    opacity: 0.8,
    // Прозрачность у медианной по весу точки.
    intensityOfMidpoint: 0.2,
    // JSON описание градиента.
    gradient: {
        0.1: 'rgba(128, 255, 0, 0.7)',
        0.2: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.8)',
        0.7: 'rgba(234, 72, 58, 0.9)',
        1.0: 'rgba(162, 36, 25, 1)'
    }
});
heatmap.setMap(myMap);
});
```

Кстати есть отличная документация https://github.com/yandex/mapsapi-heatmap

Comment: Да изучил же))) Я так понимаю, речь идет о параметре "вес точки"? В документации он ниразу не описан. Мельком упоминается в статье на ХАБРе и все.

Comment: Ну как же не описан, в самом низу в доке есть "Weighted points.")

Comment: А как сделать всё тоже самое, но загружать данные через LoadingObjectManager?